# How do I get pages from another folder than views?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In a Sinatra script, I have code that checks if a file exists, then shows it with the proper rendering. The files are located under `\views`:

```
get '/:page' do
  if File.exists?('views/'+params[:page]+'.slim')
    slim params[:page].to_sym
  else
    raise error(404) 
  end   
end
```

I want these files in `\public`. How do I do this please?:

```
get '/:page' do
  if File.exists?('public/'+params[:page]+'.slim')
    slim "/public/"+params[:page].to_sym #=> error
  else
    raise error(404) 
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it:

```
slim "../public/#{params[:page]}".to_sym
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Sinatra docs: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

There, you'll notice that you can set the `:views` property, which should handle what you need. Their example sets it to the `templates/` dir in the app root:

```
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "templates") }
```